# How to add error bars and customize stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval, stacked-chart

I have a dataset and stacked bar chart similar to what’s shown below. The chart is for prevalence of a specific disease (CVD=0 for no, 1 for yes) over time, by treatment type (trt=1 or 2).

I am wondering if someone could please help me with:

1. Adding N for sample size under each visit number. For example, under visit=0, N=7, under visit=1, N=7, and so on.
2. Annotate the graph with point estimate for prevalence of CVD and error bars for the confidence intervals? I would like the prevalence estimates to have 95% confidence intervals to better appreciate whether there was difference between treatment 1 and 2.
3. get a separate table with the actual numbers for the confidence intervals.
4. what is the best way to check/show if

a) change over time was statistically significant
b) are there statistically significant differences between trt 1 and 2?

Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Here’s a mock dataset similar to what I am working on and some code I’ve used to generate the stacked plot.

```
ID = c(001, 001, 001, 001, 001, 002, 002, 002, 003, 003, 004, 004, 004, 004, 005, 005, 006, 007, 007, 007, 008, 008, 008, 008, 008, 009, 009, 009, 009, 009)
Visit = c(00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 00, 01, 02,  01, 02, 00, 01, 02, 03, 00, 02, 00, 01, 02, 04, 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 00, 01, 02, 03, 04)
CVD = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,  1, 0, 0, 1, 1,  0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
TRT= c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
BIO=c(12.00, 11.9, 15.24, 13.10, 30.01, 45.90, 20.09, 23.45, 14.78, 18.05,
      24.23, 12.34, 80.01, 13.98, 12.50, 36.95, 29.00, 39.87, 19.03, 11.48,
      14.14, 28.06, 12.22, 72.08, 15.00, 11.33, 58.00, 17.71, 52.08, 15.25)
df<-data.frame(ID,Visit, CVD, TRT, BIO)
percentData <- df %>% group_by(Visit, TRT) %>% count(CVD) %>%
 mutate(ratio=scales::percent(n/sum(n))) %>% 
  ungroup()
ggplot(df,aes(x=Visit,fill=factor(CVD)))+
  geom_bar(position="fill")+ facet_wrap(~TRT)+
  geom_text(data=percentData, aes(y=n,label=ratio),
            position=position_fill(vjust=0.5))+
  ylab('Percentage')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a lot to ask in a single question. The way I would tackle this is to first of all generate a data frame with all the numbers you will need for plotting *and* tabling results:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(Visit, TRT) %>% 
  summarize(no_CVD = table(factor(CVD, 0:1))[1],
            CVD = table(factor(CVD, 0:1))[2],
            n = no_CVD + CVD,
            prop = CVD / n,
            lower = suppressWarnings(prop.test(CVD, n)$conf.int[1]),
            upper = suppressWarnings(prop.test(CVD, n)$conf.int[2])) %>%
  mutate(Percent = scales::percent(prop, 0.1),
         CI = paste0("(", scales::percent(lower, 0.1), " - ",
                     scales::percent(upper, 0.1), ")"),
         TRT = paste("Treatment", TRT))
```

You can see this gives us the point estimates and confidence intervals as both raw proportions and as text labels, which should be adequate to fulfill question 3:

```r
df2
#> # A tibble: 10 x 10
#> # Groups:   Visit [5]
#>    Visit TRT         no_CVD   CVD     n  prop  lower upper Percent CI           
#>    <dbl> <chr>        <int> <int> <int> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>        
#>  1     0 Treatment 1      3     1     4 0.25  0.0132 0.781 25.0%   (1.3% - 78.1~
#>  2     0 Treatment 2      0     3     3 1     0.310  1     100.0%  (31.0% - 100~
#>  3     1 Treatment 1      2     2     4 0.5   0.150  0.850 50.0%   (15.0% - 85.~
#>  4     1 Treatment 2      2     1     3 0.333 0.0177 0.875 33.3%   (1.8% - 87.5~
#>  5     2 Treatment 1      1     3     4 0.75  0.219  0.987 75.0%   (21.9% - 98.~
#>  6     2 Treatment 2      3     1     4 0.25  0.0132 0.781 25.0%   (1.3% - 78.1~
#>  7     3 Treatment 1      0     2     2 1     0.198  1     100.0%  (19.8% - 100~
#>  8     3 Treatment 2      1     1     2 0.5   0.0945 0.905 50.0%   (9.5% - 90.5~
#>  9     4 Treatment 1      1     2     3 0.667 0.125  0.982 66.7%   (12.5% - 98.~
#> 10     4 Treatment 2      1     0     1 0     0      0.945 0.0%    (0.0% - 94.5~
```

To put the N under each visit, we can simply `paste` the visit number with a string containing the counts from this table (this handles question 1).

Question 2 is a little odd. The sample prevalence of CVD was already present on your plot (that's what the blue bars showed). Adding error bars to a stacked bar graph is going to look messy, and the bars don't actually give any information that a simple point does in this scenario. I have therefore changed the plot to show points with error bars.

```r
ggplot(df2, aes(paste0(Visit, "\n(n = ", n, ")"), prop)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper, color = factor(TRT)), 
                size = 1, width = 0.25) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(Percent, CI, sep = "\n"), y = 1.1), size = 3) +
  facet_grid(.~TRT, scales = "free_x") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, name = "CVD Prevalance") +
  xlab("Visit") +
  theme_light(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

[image]

Your last two points are statistical rather than programming questions, so are off-topic here. It is likely that you need a binomial generalized linear mixed model to handle the repeated measures, but you should post that question on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), our sister site for stats questions if you do not have access to a statistician.

<sup>Created on 2022-06-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>